# How to make parent Activity class data accessible inside OnClickListener?

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener, class-variables

In an Android Activity class which implements a ListView, I have an OnClickListener which I can't seem to get any data from the class. The class has Strings, Arrays, JSONObjects, any of which would be helpful if only they were accessible inside the OnClickListener function. How is this done? Also sorry Stackoverflow and everyone else because I can't seem to make "Class CompanyListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {" appear inside the code block. Just pretend it is there.

Class CompanyListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
lateinit var arrCompany: Array<Array<String?>>

arrCompany = // some valid data...

var mListView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listviewCompanyListCompanies)

mListView.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _, _, index, _ ->

        val intent = Intent (this@CompanyListActivity, CompanyActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("Response", arrCompany[index])  // no data in arrCompany
        startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: Well all should be accessable. What is the problem?

Comment: intent.putExtra("Response", arrCompany[index])  // no data in arrCompany

Comment: Then put data in it. Some valid data.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this was clear: arrCompany = // some valid data...

Comment: "no data in arrCompany": Do you mean you get an IndexOutOfBounds exception? Or do you mean the `CompanyActivity` receives `null` when it tries to retrieve the `"Response"` extra? Or something else?

Comment: The CompanyActivity receives null when it tries to retrieve the "Response" extra. arrCompany is null when debugging inside the OnItemClickListener function. It has valid data inside the class before the click event.

Comment: Solved: I added a public Getter function to the Parent Activity class

Answer (score 0):

Add a public Getter function to the Parent Activity class:

```
public fun GetCompanyArray (i: Int?): Array<String?> {
    return arrCompany[i!!] 
}
```

Then call it inside the OnClickListerner function:

```
var arrResponse = GetCompanyArray(index)
```